# adding dynamic columns to DataGrid - how can I set different cell templates for a column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a DataGrid bound to a DataTable, and clicking on a button on the View adds a new column to the DataTable in the ViewModel which is then reflected in the DataGrid. So far so good.

My DataTable has columns of type object and into the first row of a column I have an Enum value and then just text for all remaining entries in the column. By default, the DataGrid columns turn out to be of type DataGridTextColumn and all cells are TextBox.

The problem is that I want the first row in each new DataGrid column to be a combo box, while all other cells in the column should display standard text.

I've discovered that you can set the CellTemplateSelector and CellEditingTemplateSelector on columns in order to do this but since I'm creating columns dynamically I can't set this up (or I can't see how to).

Any ideas? Three days working on this and counting!

Comment: I'm really sorry if my comment is not appropiate, but do you think you could transpose the columns and rows? I find unusual that you have to add new dynamic columns and that the first row is a combo. If transposed having the first column as combobox and adding rows dynamically sounds more familiar. Again sorry if this is appropiate as I don't know the context of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the business requires that the first row be a combo box, otherwise transposing would make things easier, as you say. I'm starting to think perhaps having a DataTable backing this isn't the way to go...